# Raster calculator - problems with syntax

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, pixel, syntax

I have a raster layer with values ranging from 0.00597303 to 0.102894 and I want to assign specific number representing a group to specific range of values:

```
Group 4: x >= 0.1
Group 3: 0.01 <= x < 0.1
Group 2: x < 0.01
```

I am using the following syntax:

```
("Ri_Q50@1" >= 0.1) * 4 + (("Ri_Q50@1" >= 0.01) AND ("Ri_Q50@1" < 0.1)) * 3 + ("Ri_Q50@1" < 0.01) * 2
```

However, the output file only has assigned group 2 and 3 but not the 4th group (x >= 0.1). What could be the reason?

Note: When I use the Raster pixels to points and check the output point layer there is 12 points having exceeded the condition for 4th group - ie 12 pixels has value above 0.1).

Comment: I am using Qgis.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Petr! Your expression looks fine, which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I've tried 3.4 long term release and 3.8 Zanzibar but both gives the same output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Raster Calculator, you can use Reclassify by table tool from `Processing toolbox -> Raster Analysis -> Reclassify by table`. Then use the range of values that you want to reclassify to integer values as you can see in the example below:

[image]

Make sure to select the correct Range boundaries from the tool above. This example uses `min < value <= max`. You may need to change it based on your desired analysis.

Comment: Thanks for tip, however the Range boundaries of this tool does not allow me to reclassify the raster according to my needs:

Group 4: x >= 0.1

Group 3: 0.01 <= x < 0.1

Group 2: x < 0.01