# Merging three rasters into one

Tags: raster, qgis-3, raster-calculator, merge

I need to merge 3 rasters into one, each raster is single banded and ranges from 0 to 1. The rasters overlap at some places. Below is how each raster looks like and how the output should look like using Raster Calculator or merged, however the result using syntax `rastr1 * raster2* raster3` is that the output raster values ranges from 0 to 0 and the merge tools do not correct the output either.

I am using QGIS 3.8.

[image: Raster1]
[image: Raster2]
[image: Raster3]
[image: merged]

Comment: Have you tried `raster1 + raster 2 + raster 3`?

Comment: Yes, the result is not satisfying.

Comment: @Petr - Did you try using the `Build Virtual Raster` tool?

Comment: It would help if you provided a little more clarity on what you're trying to achieve. Do you simply want to make a binary raster that is "1" wherever there was data in any of the rasters, or do you want to somehow retain the original raster values from each?

Comment: @Joseph I tried that tool but the result is not satisfying.

Comment: @Jon I am trying to achive merging all three rasters into one that corresponds to the very last picture (which is a screen shot of all three layers toggled on). I want to achive the following order: red color has value "2", blue color has value "1", orange color has value "0". This is supposed to be a flood plain. I've extracted those separate rasters from layer (which serves as base for defining the probability of flood event) using raster calculator. I've tried to extract all three raster layers from the original layer using the raster calculator but I was not successful and I was looking

Comment: @Jon for help here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330511/raster-calculator-problems-with-syntax

Comment: Have you tried a conditional statement: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141305/conditional-calculation-qgis-raster-calculator-or-grass-r-mapcalculator

Comment: @NathanThomas I've tried that using ("Ri_Q50@1" >= 0.1) * 4 + (("Ri_Q50@1" >= 0.01) AND ("Ri_Q50@1" < 0.1)) * 3 + ("Ri_Q50@1" < 0.01) * 2. I wanted to assign the values 4, 3, and 2 to the specific range of values of one raster. However, the resault turned out to be not what was expected. I have one input layer and I want to change its pixel values according to the syntax above. The pixels of input layer ranges from 0.00597 to 0.10298 - I want to replace these pixel values for the values 4, 3, and 2 according to the range mentioned in the syntax.

Comment: With this approach I was not successful therefore I was looking for other solution. So I've selected the values x< 0.01;  0.01<=x<0.1; x>=0.1 separately and it worked(the output are above posted pictures) then I wanted to merge them, but the result is not correct. I am really hopeless now...

Comment: @Petr this may be easier for you if we break int into steps. Use the raster calculator to set the values in each raster as either 1, 2 3 or 4. Then mosaic/merge them in the   order you want. when merging datasets they are added to the new image in the order you list them, so in your above example raster 1 would be at the 'bottom' and raster 4 would be on 'top'

Comment: @NathanThomas But this approach does not work neither. The output of the apporach you've suggested is far away from what depicts the very last picture I've uploded (all three layers toggled on). I really don't know whats wrong. The sytanx should work but it doesn't the merge tool shoudl work but it calculates some wierd raster output. Do you have any other idea? I've also tried to use the tool reclassify raster but as my range of values uses inconsistent formating (sometime <, then =>) I really can't define the table used for reclassification.

Comment: @Petr ok, lets try breaking it down further, step by step. You have 3 rasters correct? and they are binary images, correct? Make sure that there are only 1's and 0's. And you can use raster calculator to give each one a value? So raster 1 will be 3 and 0, raster 2 will be 2 and 0 and raster 3 will be 3 and 0? Can you get to this stage?

Comment: @NathanThomas Thanks for patience. I have finally found the "error" the thing was that the min max value was just "estimate" and not actual, and as the max value of original raster was just abouve 0.1 (0.010298)  the setting of symbology of the layer was defined in way that it was not showing the last cathegory (the 4th one) thats why I was missing all the time the last cathegory and desparately was looking for other solutions.

Comment: @Petr Glad you figured it out! It did sound like there were anomalies in your data which is why I wanted you to check if your data only had 1s and 0s. In your answer below, you should add what steps you took to finally get your result (raster calculator etc), as this my be useful to others

Answer (score 1):

The "error" was that the min max value was just "estimate" and not actual, and as the max value of original raster was just above 0.1 (0.010298) the setting of symbology of the layer (it was estimated) was defined in way that it was not showing the last cathegory (the 4th one) thats why I was missing all the time the last cathegory.